# Raspberry pi using a button as a toggle for a servo

Tags: python, button, toggle, servo, raspberry-pi-zero

I have a raspberry pi using pigpio to control two servos with two buttons. Right now I have to hold the button to make the servo move. I want the buttons to toggle the servos between the two positions, but my attempts fail.

I'm on mobile so i put a picture of my code, sorry I couldn't paste it.
[Code Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bskHi.png)

Note: the commented code is from when i was using gpiozero to control the servos, but it caused jittering so I switched to pigpio. The comments are there just in case I have to switch back for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

To toggle between positions you need to know when the positions are reached.

- Do you have limit switches?
- Can you measure the increase in current when the motor reaches the limit?
- Can you send the motor to a position by setting an angle?

Comment: No to the first 2, Yes to the third, but I dont see why I would need to do those things when my code works right now, I just need help turning it into a toggle between the max and min rotations

Comment: Please add code, not pictures of code. StackOverflow is not a free coding service. Usually people come here with some specific problem and get help. Put together some code to show that you tried on your own and come back with a detailed question.